# % of Total by group

Tags: sql-server, percentage, subtotal

I have three columns in MyTable and I need to calculate % of total by each group.

Code:

`SELECT AppVintage, Strategy, Apps
FROM mytable
GROUP BY AppVintage,Strategy,Apps`

Each date appears 4 times, with a different class for each line and then a total of applications for each line.

The table looks something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfPai.png]

Code for the sample data set:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
AppVintage VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,Strategy   VARCHAR(28) NOT NULL
,Apps       INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(AppVintage,Strategy,Apps) VALUES ('Nov16','300',10197);
INSERT INTO mytable(AppVintage,Strategy,Apps) VALUES ('Nov-16','ORIG',29023);
INSERT INTO mytable(AppVintage,Strategy,Apps) VALUES ('Nov-16','400',7219);
INSERT INTO mytable(AppVintage,Strategy,Apps) VALUES ('Nov-16','500',9452);
INSERT INTO mytable(AppVintage,Strategy,Apps) VALUES ('Dec-16','300',12517);
INSERT INTO mytable(AppVintage,Strategy,Apps) VALUES ('Dec-16','ORIG',37762);
INSERT INTO mytable(AppVintage,Strategy,Apps) VALUES ('Dec-16','400',8992);
INSERT INTO mytable(AppVintage,Strategy,Apps) VALUES ('Dec-16','500',11229);'
```

What I need is to add a column that calculates percentage of apps per strategy for each appvintage.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use window functions to do this (Assuming SQL Server 2008+)

```
SELECT
    AppVintage,
    Strategy,
    Apps,
    Apps/SUM(Apps) OVER (PARTITION BY AppVintage) as Percent_Apps
FROM myTable
```